# pgfplots: problem in the legend using custom marks

Tags: pgfplots, legend

With the help of `\pgfdeclareplotmark` I defined a custom mark for a plot and it worked as expected; however, in the legend, the mark appears with a vertical shift. What is causing this problem and how can it be prevented?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\pgfdeclareplotmark{*)}
  {\shade[draw=green!60!black,ball color=green!70] (0,0) circle [radius=5pt];}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[mark=*)]  
coordinates {
 (-2,3)
 (1,-5)
};
\addlegendentry{test}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interestingly, this can be fixed by using `(0pt, 0pt)` instead of `(0,0)` in the plot mark definition. Some PGF vs. TikZ problem, perhaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\pgfdeclareplotmark{*)}
  {\shade[draw=green!60!black,ball color=green!70] (0pt, 0pt) circle [radius=5pt];}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[mark=*)]  
coordinates {
 (-2,3)
 (1,-5)
};
\addlegendentry{test}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ha! I tried almost everything, except the simplest thing :-) Thank you, Jake.

Comment: Indeed (0,0) is the origin of the corrected legend box but the legend bounding box increases due to the wrongly placed ball. This is most probably due to the TikZ parsing of the coordinate inside the pgf pen syntax.

Comment: Jake and @percusse: would you say this is a bug, a feature, or simply a mistake I made by not providing explicitly a unit?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think it is unpredictable behavior. Consider using `\pgfdeclareplotmark{*)}{
\tikzset{ball color=green!70}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{green!60!black}
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
\pgfshadepath{ball}{0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}}` then there is no issue whether there is `pt` or not (you can even use `\pgfpointorigin`). Does that make it a bug? Jake and Christian know way better than me.