# Let custom mark depend on a variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to create a custom mark to use in a scatterplot. [pgfplots: problem in the legend using custom marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125451/pgfplots-problem-in-the-legend-using-custom-marks) has provided a hint on how to proceed but I do not know how to make this mark depend on a third variable. For example, the code below, is it possible to have `\pgfdeclareplotmark` get the `\node` label (which I have hard-coded with `{a}` below) from the `label` column in the data?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
 y x label
 1 1     a
 2 2     b
 3 3     c
 }\testdata
 
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myshape} {\node[draw, rounded corners=2pt, color=blue, fill=white] {a};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
  \addplot[ mark=myshape] table[x=x, y=y] {\testdata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what I'd like to achieve with the labels. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be an option to use `nodes near coords` instead?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableread{
 y x label
 1 1     a
 2 2     b
 3 3     c
 }\testdata
 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[
     point meta=explicit symbolic,
     nodes near coords,
     nodes near coords align=center,
     nodes near coords style={draw, rounded corners=2pt, color=blue, fill=white}
     ] table[x=x, y=y, meta=label] {\testdata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you Torbjørn